# Determining interval(s) containing the smallest prime $p$ of an RSA modulus?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis

Are there any results that have determined interval(s) $$b\sqrt{n}<p\leq a\sqrt{n},$$ where $0<b<1$, $0<a\le 1$, and $p<q$ are primes such that $n=pq$,

thus allowing us to narrow the search for $p$?

Comment: The standard strategy is to always set the highest bit of the prime and generating the rest randomly, this works fairly well. If your modulus should have an uneven length, you could approximate by setting the highest byte to an approximation of $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @SEJPM: the problem with such a simple approach (setting the highest bit, selecting randomly otherwise) is that you have a 50-50 chance at generating an $n-1$ bit modulus.  Personally, when I ask an implementation to generate a 1024 bit modulus, and it generates a 1023 bit one, I treat that as suspect, even though a 1023 bit number is not measurably easier to factor.  1024 bit RSA modulii have a specific definition, and if they got that wrong, I wonder what else they got wrong that's not so obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Any such nontrivial intervals would be entirely up to the implementation generating the RSA key.  For example, when generating a 2048 bit RSA key, an implementation could generate a 512 bit $p$ and a 1536 bit $q$; such a modulus would work just as well in RSA as any other modulus; this gives us an $a \approx 2^{512}$.

However, while an implementation could do that, they never do; instead, they generally aim to keep $p$ and $q$ balanced; one advantage this has is that it allows the maximum speed-up by the CRT algorithm.

I've seen two different strategies in common use; if we assume $n$ is even, then to generate an $n$-bit RSA modulus, we often either:

- Generate two random $n/2$ bit primes with the two high bits set (which ensures that, when $p$ and $q$ are multiplied together, yield a $n$-bit modulus, and not an $n-1$ bit.
- Generate two random primes both from the range $(2^{(n-1)/2}, 2^{n/2})$, which yields the same effect, albeit in a slightly more mathematical way.

With the first strategy, we have $\sqrt{3/4}\sqrt{n} < p < \sqrt{n}$; in the second strategy, we have $\sqrt[4]{1/2}\sqrt{n} < p < \sqrt{n}$ (a slightly wider interval).

As I mentioned earlier, there's no requirement that any specific RSA implementation uses either strategy (unless they claim FIPS compliance; FIPS insists on the second strategy).

In addition, you appear to be interested in this to help in searching for factors of RSA modulii; for any RSA modulii that's even slightly secure, the interval is *far* too wide to make any such simple-minded search for factors feasible.